# Avoid cutting markup elements within xml nodes using PHP

Tags: php, xml, docbook-5

I want to parse a DocBook XML file with PHP. SimpleXMLElement cuts off some markup elements.

```
<section>
<title>SUSPEND</title>
    <para>The <database>SUSPEND</database> command <quote>breaks</quote> the atomicity of the block in which it is located.</para>
    <para>...</para>
</section>
```

I use this code to parse my para elements:

```
$paras = $xml->xpath("//*[starts-with(local-name(), 'para')]");
foreach($paras as $para) {
   echo $para[0];
}
```

This cuts off my markup

```
<database>SUSPEND</database> and <quote>breaks</quote>
```

resulting in

```
The command the atomicity of the block in which it is located.
```

But what I need is:

```
The <database>SUSPEND</database> command <quote>breaks</quote> the atomicity of the block in which it is located.
```

So how can I get the whole node including its elements as string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [asXML](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php) method to get tree with root at element found

```
foreach($paras as $para) {
   echo $para->asXML();
}
```